# solr shema not considered inside dataset

Tags: solr

I am struggling to add another data field to my shema.

the entry looks correct:

```
<field name="user_name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
```

It also apears if I output the shema via the interface.

However, after an import this field is not present. I have an entity in dataimport.xml that imports that field.

Querying solr returns the result set without the field even mentioned.

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: please show more details. add your schema.xml, DIH config

Comment: did u restart the solr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

restart the Solr server after changing schema and then

you should see the field through solr tool ... if not then you are not changing the correct schema.xml file

As you made the "required" attribute is false.

and the meaning of it is

required : Solr will reject any attempts to add a document which does not have a value for this field. This property defaults to false.

Comment: thank you for the hint. problem was, value was empty due to false mysql statement returning 0